# RVO or move for std::list

Tags: c++, move-semantics, return-value-optimization

I have the following implementation which returns the last element of a `std::list<T>` and deletes it from the list:

```
  std::list<T> list_;

  T ReturnAndDeleteLast( )const
  {
    T last( list_.back() );  // copy it before delete it. 
    list_.pop_back();
    return last;
  }
```

Now the question is when calling it like:

```
 T tmp{};

 for( .... )
 {
  // do we want to delete at this iteration?
  //YES:
    tmp = ReturnAndDeleteLast();
  // do something with tmp..
 }
```

The question is if a `std::move` would be more efficient in this case or should I rely on RVO.

Comment: Are you asking if you should be using `return std::move(last);`?  If so, then no.  All function local automatic storage duration objects are automatically moved if they can be and then copied if they cant be moved.

Comment: You *could* do `T last( std::move(list_.back()) );` for potential gains. Of course, the puzzling bit is why you have a `const` member function mutating what appears to be a member list.

Comment: `return std::move(last);` prevent NRVO. `return last;` might do NRVO, and at worst move (as list is moveable).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I was thinking about doing that. But I am not sure what happens to the object at `list_.back()`. Is it removeD? Does it mean I, For example, don't need the `list_.pop_back()`?

Comment: No, that's not how move semantics work. You have a modified object left there in some destructible/assignable state. You pop to eliminate it. But any resources it may have had internally are already moved to the local `last`. Think shallow copy instead of deep copy as you have now.

Comment: If you are not certain, add `printf` into T move constructor and move assignment. You will see that it prints `T(&&)` and `=T(&&)`. If you care about performance, you better to define variable at the point of the `ReturnAndDeleteLast` function call. In this case move assignment won't be called.